# Error loading SDF in Gazebo 1.3.1

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm trying to load a simple SDF in Gazebo and I'm getting an error.

I'm running Gazebo 1.3.1.

The SDF is copied straight from [a tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.3/build_robot/mobile_base). The code is:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<sdf version='1.3'>
  <model name="my_robot">
     <static>true</static>
       <link name='chassis'>
        <pose>0 0 .1 0 0 0</pose>

        <collision name='collision'>
          <geometry>
            <box>
              <size>.4 .2 .1</size>
            </box>
          </geometry>
        </collision>

        <visual name='visual'>
          <geometry>
            <box>
              <size>.4 .2 .1</size>
            </box>
          </geometry>
        </visual>
      </link>
  </model>
</sdf>
```

I tried to launch it using:

```
gzfactory spawn -f model3.sdf
```

The error I'm getting is this:

```
Error [SDF.cc:984] Unable to find value for key[origin]
Error [SDF.cc:738] Missing element description for [origin]
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Someone else posted about this error [here](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/433/gzfactory-spawning-not-working-in-gazebo-12/).  It was said to be fixed in the bug report, but I don't think it was.

Is there a fix for this? Is there a better way to spawn an SDF?

**Verdict: Probably a bug.  Filed [here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/455/gzfactory-broken) . Workaround: Follow the directions given in the answer below or equivalently in the [Gazebo Handbook](http://gazebosim.org/user_guide/started__models__database.html).**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/854/error-loading-sdf-in-gazebo-1.3.1/) by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 175 on 2013-01-15

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daehyung Park](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/114/daehyung-park/) on 2013-01-21**:
I have same problem. Any solution?

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-01-21**:
Perhaps upvoting the question will get it more attention from the admins. (And a solution is given below by Andrei).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I had the same problem :).

The workaround I used, I copied all my models into ~/.gazebo/models folder. Then you can either spawn them from gazebo. Or by adding these lines to the .world file:

```
<world>
...
    <include>
        <uri>model://my_robot</uri>
        <pose>0.3 0.5 0.9 0 0 0</pose>
    </include>
</world>
```

It is weird they still haven't fixed this bug. It is not very portable having the models in that folder.

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2013-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-01-21**:
Works!  Thanks for the answer.  Perhaps upvoting the question will get this bug more attention from the admins.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

[A patch has been applied for this problem in simulator_gazebo 1.7.11 groovy](http://ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/ChangeList/1.7#A1.7.11_.282013-02-05.29), [deb built will begin soon](http://www.ros.org/debbuild/groovy.html).

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-02-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1